# Unwrapping Restangular service promise / view not getting updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, restangular

I'm trying to unwrap a promise so that my view gets updated when I click a submit button. In the controller, I first call `getProfileDetails()` that returns an object of details. Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('duskWeb').controller('ProfileController', function(Profile) {
  'ngInject';
  var activate, getProfileDetails, passItemsToScope, vm;
  vm = this;
  activate = function() {
    getProfileDetails();
  };
  getProfileDetails = function() {
    return Profile.getDetails(userid).then(passItemsToScope);
  };
  vm.submit = function() {
    return Profile.editDetails(updateParams).then(passItemsToScope);
  };
  passItemsToScope = function(data) {
    vm.profileDetails = data;
  };
  activate();
});
```

In the service `Profile`, I am using Restangular to retrieve the profile details object as well as use the post function to update the profile details. Here is the service:

```
angular.module('duskWeb').service('Profile', function(API) {
  var Profile;
  return new (Profile = (function() {
    function Profile() {
      this.getDetails;
      this.editDetails;
    }

    Profile.prototype.getDetails = function(id) {
      var getDetailsComplete;
      getDetailsComplete = function(response) {
        return response.data;
      };
      return API.one('creator/' + id).get().then(getDetailsComplete, function(message) {
        return console.log('Error: ' + message.status);
      });
    };

    Profile.prototype.editDetails = function(params) {
      var editDetailsComplete;
      editDetailsComplete = function(response) {
        toastr.success("Successfully updated profile");
        return response.data;
      };
      return API.all('user').post({
        email: params.email,
        first_name: params.firstName,
        last_name: params.lastName,
        display_name: params.displayName,
        location: params.location
      }).then(editDetailsComplete, function(message) {
        return console.log('Error: ' + message.status);
      });
    };

    return Profile;

  })());
});
```

Here is what the API service looks like, again, using Restangular:

```
angular.module('duskWeb').service('API', function(Restangular, toastr, $window, $state) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    var headers, showToastr;
    headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
      'X-DuskFM-Token': ''
    };
    showToastr = function(message) {
      toastr.info(message);
    };
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:5050/v1')
    .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
    .setFullResponse(true)
    .setResponseExtractor(function(response, method, endpoint) {
      if (response.errors === false && method !== 'get') {
        showToastr('Your request has been done successfully.');
      }
      return response;
    }).setErrorInterceptor(function(response) {
      var error;
      if (response.status >= 400 && response.status <= 499) {
        for (error in response.data.errors) {
          return showToastr(response.data.errors[error][0]);
        }
      }
      if (response.status === 500) {
        return showToastr(response.statusText);
      }
    }).addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, what, url, headers) {
      var token;
      token = $window.localStorage.satellizer_token;
      if (token) {
        headers['X-DuskFM-Token'] = token;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Right now, the view is not updating when I click submit. What I would like to happen is for the view to be updated dynamically when vm.submit() is called in the view. Any idea why this is not happening? Everything else is working (the profile gets updated and when I refresh the page, I get the updates).

Thank you.